# Is it safe to store a password in the SecurityContext in a custom Authentication implementation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have created a custom `AuthenticationProvider`, so I have to return an `Authentication` implementation with the username and password of the user (for example `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` or a custom implementation). This instance of the `Authentication` implementation will be stored in the `SecurityContext`. Is this a good practice? Is the password safetly stored? Thanks!

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private SSOClient ssoClient;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String id = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        ssoClient.login(id, password);
        return new CustomAuthenticationToken(id, password);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` as far as I can see, as long as your password is not plaintext stored which I hope it isn't anyway. For the most part, the way to implement a custom Authentication is to use this class so it shouldn't really be an issue.

Comment: @px06 that's the issue. It there a propper way to configure `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` like an `userDetailsService` to use a passwordEncoder for the credentials?

Comment: I don't think there's a need to configure it by looking at [this](https://github.com/awslabs/amediamanager/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amediamanager/service/UserServiceImpl.java#L101). If you call `authentication.getCredentials().toString();` and your password is stored as a hash, then you should be able to verify the hash with the `User` object.

Comment: What do you mean with "stored"? The Object that implements SecurityContext only exists in the memory and is not accessible. If you encrypt the password sooner or later you will need to unencrypt it. Also remember that (if possible) is always better to store hashes than passwords.

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez I mean to store the password in a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think its not safe to store password in security conext as the security context is accessible across the application. i recommend we use the password from the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken to authenticate and get rid of it.